# Tag soup clean up

Tags: discussion, tags

The following list contains tags for which I cannot see any practical use. They are way too vague, probably just [meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).
What should we do with those tags?

- [body](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/body)
- [bulk-import](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bulk-import) – we have also [bulk](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bulk) and [import](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/import)
- [challenge](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/challenge)
- [code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code)
- [coding](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding)
- [create](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/create)
- [customization](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customization)
- [default](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/default) and [defaults](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defaults)
- [deleted](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deleted) and [deleting](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deleting)
- [duplicates](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/duplicates)
- [field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field)
- [foreach](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreach)
- [fragment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fragment)
- [handling](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handling)
- [id](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/id)
- [lifetime](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lifetime)
- [list](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list) and [lists](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lists)
- [management](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/management)
- [merging](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/merging)
- [modifications](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modifications)
- [multiple](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple)
- [next](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/next)
- [parse](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parse)
- [paths](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paths)
- [permissions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permissions)
- [pre](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pre)
- [previous](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/previous)
- [recursive](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recursive)
- [registered](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/registered)
- [tag:rem. April oval]
- [reset](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reset)
- [save](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/save)
- [scale](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scale)
- [sharing](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharing)
- [sort](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sort) and [sorting](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting)
- [split](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/split)
- [structure](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structure) and [structuring](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structuring)
- [switch](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/switch)
- [table](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table)
- [text](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text)
- [theory](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theory)
- [transfer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transfer)
- [troubleshooting](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/troubleshooting)
- [type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/type)
- [ui](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ui)
- [update](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update) and [updates](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/updates)

### Already merged by me today

- [guid](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guid) with [guids](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guids),
- [header](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/header) with [headers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headers),
- [img](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/img) with [images](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images)
- [l18n](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l18n) (!) with [i18n](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/i18n)
- [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/link) with [links](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/links),
- [meta-box](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-box) with [metabox](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metabox),
- [permalink](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permalink) with [permalinks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permalinks),
- [previewing](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/previewing) with [previews](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/previews),
- [profile](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/profile) with [profiles](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/profiles),
- [user](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user) with [users](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/users) and
- [global](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/global) with [globals](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/globals).

### Merged 29. April

- [comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comment) with [comments](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comments)
- [directory](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directory) with [directories](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directories)? Related: [folder-structure](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/folder-structure)
- [localization](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/localization) with [l10n](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l10n). Which one should be canonical?]
- [page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/page) with [pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pages)
- [pictures](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pictures) with [images](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images)
- [uploading](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uploading) with [uploads](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uploads)
- [loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loop) with [loops](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loops) and [the-loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-loop)? Lingua wordpressiana prefers the singular …

What about [automate](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automate) and [automation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automation)? Do we need one of them? If so: which one?

### Merge candidates

- [multisite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multisite) with [network](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/network)
- [registration](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/registration) with [signup](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signup)

Why is [custom-fields](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-fields) linked to [custom-field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-field)? We prefer the plural usually.

### Related articles on Stack Exchange

- [How do I correctly tag my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions)
- [Should I remove tags that don't contribute to categorizing the question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46035/should-i-remove-tags-that-dont-contribute-to-categorizing-the-question)
- [Why do we tag questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31776/why-do-we-tag-questions)
- [The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

  > If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.
  >   If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.

Comment: Leave [tag:challenge] in. I like the idea.

Comment: You can probably add [`<php>`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php) to the list as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just my 2 cents:

- [body](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/body) *delete*
- [bulk-import](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bulk-import) leave, as there can be problems/errors during bulk import actions
- - [bulk](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bulk) *delete*
- - and [import](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/import) leave as you can import other stuff too
- [challenge](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/challenge) Afaik, this was incorporated by @MikeSchinkel in the early days of WPSE
- [code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code) *delete*
- [coding](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coding) *delete*
- [create](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/create) *delete*
- [customization](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customization) *delete*
- [default](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/default) and [defaults](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defaults) merge to plural
- [deleted](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deleted) and [deleting](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deleting) no idea. in detail they're different, but I'm not sure if they really add any value and so it's simply too broad in scope.
- [duplicates](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/duplicates) again: too broad scope but somehow valid. Let's see if this gets more detail with example [dublicate-posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dublicate-posts), etc. Then every "sub"-tag could be made a synonym of the [duplicates](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/duplicates)
- [field](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/field) *delete*
- [foreach](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreach) *delete*
- [fragment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fragment) *delete*
- [handling](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handling) *delete*
- [id](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/id) pfffft
- [lifetime](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lifetime) *delete*
- [list](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list) and [lists](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lists) again: too broad scope, but no idea
- [management](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/management) *delete*
- [merging](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/merging) too broad scope
- [modifications](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modifications) *delete*
- [multiple](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple) *delete*
- [next](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/next) this would normally apply to pagination stuff what we've got a lot. could be made a synonym of [pagination](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pagination)
- [parse](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parse) no good Qs there, so *delete*
- [paths](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paths) valid
- [permissions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permissions) valid, but too broad scope
- [pre](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pre) *delete*
- [previous](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/previous) see [next](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/next) ↑
- [recursive](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recursive) *delete* (php only stuff as [foreach](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreach), etc.)
- [registered](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/registered) *delete* as too broad scope
- [removal](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/removal) *delete*
- [reset](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reset) *delete* as too broad scope
- [save](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/save) valid, but too broad scope
- [scale](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scale) valid - WP is known for scaling issues when it comes to meta data for posts/taxonomies or the menu system
- [sharing](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharing) valid - could be merged if we got a [social](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social)
- [sort](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sort) and [sorting](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting) php only as mentioned with [recursive](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recursive), so  *delete*
- [split](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/split)  *delete*
- [structure](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structure) and [structuring](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structuring) *delete*
- [switch](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/switch) applies only to users and themes (afaik), so valid. But needs clean up if used in the php-meaning, which wouldn't happen too often
- [table](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/table) *delete* too broad scope, mixed meanings, etc. I'd have suggested to merge with [wp-list-table](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wp-list-table), but we already got too many posts referring to html tables.
- [text](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text) *delete*
- [theory](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theory) valid
- [transfer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transfer) no idea what that would be
- [troubleshooting](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/troubleshooting) *delete*
- [type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/type) *delete*
- [ui](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ui) valid
- [update](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update) and [updates](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/updates) merge to plural

I've written "too broad scope" several times. This means

> *»I don't think that someone would search the tag archive as the scope simply is too broad«*

Getting no real result from a search in tag archives, means the archive is useless to everyone.

When I wrote "delete", then I meant deleting the tag from all questions and wait for it to get empty.