# Two users to approve an edit?

Tags: support

Why do I have the privilege to edit anything, but when comes to approve an edit there's this (new?) message popping warning that approving an edit needs 2 reviewers? This happened to me directly in a Question page, not in the review queue.

Maybe it has to do with the issues in the review process that has been discussed in the mother ship meta. The following post has many links about the issue: [Improving the Quality of Reviews: Project Honeypot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152709/185667).

I'm not sure if the same policy is applied throughout the Stack, or if different rules are applied to each individual site of the network.

It's not really an issue for me, just found it strange given the [edit privileges one gets with 2k](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to honeypots. It needs always two reviewers to approve an edit on all sites. SO is an exception: it needs three reviewers here.

Only moderators can approve an edit immediately.

You can always see what happened with your reviews in your profile under **activity/reviews**, for example [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/7489). Looking at your [first edit review](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2628) I see it didn’t need a second review. This was probably part of the old review system.

Comment: I rephrased the honeypot part. In essence: does this has to do with the quality control of the review process? Just because I had the impression that once I did approve some edits at once... But just thinking about it, maybe another approval was done prior to mine and I thought I was the only one doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Found the relevant posts in Meta StackOverflow:

[How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/185667)

> #### Who can vote on a suggested edit?
>
> - The owner of a post may cast a binding vote to accept or reject any modification of their post.
> - All users with the [edit privilege](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) may vote on
>     suggested edits to posts.
> - Users with [5000 rep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits)
>     may vote on suggested edits to tag wikis.
> - Two accept or reject votes are required to remove the suggested edit from the queue and either apply the edit to the post or discard it.
>     [It used to be a single
>     vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151586/59303)

Another one (nice title btw):

[It takes two to tango?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151586/185667)

> In response to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/185667), we've bumped up the number of reviews
>   required to approve or reject a suggested edit:
>
> - **Network-wide:** two reviews per edit suggestion.
> - **Stack Overflow:** three reviews per edit suggestion.

Related Blog Post:

[Suggested Edits and Edit Review](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/)