# Does my edit "not make the post even a little bit easier to read"?

Tags: discussion

I'm not a WordPress expert so can't add as many answers as I'd like but I've been trying to contribute as best I can.

Shame then that an edit on [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/112079/875) was rejected. It's a great post by gmazzap and helped me a lot.

But as an English speaker if a paragraph reads "once there is no filter or actions, or we use javascript or we modify core files" ... I'm initially confused. "or ... or" makes it sounds like there are three options.

I think he means there are two options ... ***Either*** *use Javascript or modify the core*.

But my edit was swiftly rejected. I know it's a little edit but it added clarity, I thought.

Comment: I saw your edit proposal and decided to skip to review it, hoping someone better than me at english could revise it. I also saw your revision rejected by 2 different users, one of them is a native english speaker. My english is not good enough to say how much your revision can improve readability, but normally edits that involve just one word are rejected because of "too minor", unless the word is completely wrong or misleading.

Comment: thanks giuseppe i do speak italian so i'm familiar with "o questo o quello" but in english we say "either this or that" ... but aside from that thanks for a great original post and i've checked out your code in github ... very helpful.

Comment: ... also @gmazzap when you say "my english is not good enough" you're being exceedingly modest

Comment: @gmazzap who is the native Englishs speaker, I'm a boertjie, speaking Afrikaans and cybmeta is Spanish :-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen doh! :) I read "location: South Africa" and assumed your native language was english.

Comment: Hahahaha, no, there are still some Afrikaans speaking people left in SA. I think there are now more of us in Australia than in SA, hahaha. I also from time to time still struggle with English, specially because English in SA differ from English in the UK which differs from English in the US. Confusing really. @gmazzap

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the two users who rejected your edit. Not the native English one though. My Native tongue is Afrikaans. Hahaha. Pulling G.M.'s leg a bit here :-)

On the serious side, according to me the edit was too minor and the edit did not really improve the post overall quality such, that is why I rejected it. The post author also has the opportunity to accept or reject or skip an edit on his post, which he did.

We try to keep minor edits to a minimum, as posts with excessive edits gets community wiki'ed, and that particular poster looses all reputation and future reputation on that question or answer.

You have to remember as well, most top or high reputation users don't speak English, so we at times do make mistakes with edits and in our posts. You as a non English speaker would know that. Even the native English guys do get it wrong at times.

On edits, we need two rejections to fully reject an edit, so on your post, the edit was rejected by me another user whos native tongue is Spanish.

As you are interested in constructive edits, @toscho has written a comprehensive guide to edits. It must be noted, we all still have our own descretion to edit, reject, approve or to suggest edits on merit and act within the guidelines. This rejection should not defer you from doing future edits, but encourage you to be a better editor. Feel free to read [this post](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1090/31545) on edits