# What does the "customization" tag represent?

Tags: discussion

I thought I'd spend some time filling in missing tag wiki information and came across the "customization" tag. Based on usage, I can't work out what is is supposed to represent.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customization

Nor does looking at the synonyms help.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/customization/synonyms

It appears to be used to mark anything that vaguely resembles customizing anything, which makes it a pretty useless tag in my estimation. When is anything here not an attempt to customize something?

It makes most sense to me to restrict this tag to *theme customization* which is the first thing I thought when I saw the tag, though there is already a [`theme-customizer`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme-customizer) tag. Or, just remove it altogether.

I don't want to just make-up a tag wiki to fit my gut feeling, nor can I remove the tag if I wanted. Hence this post. What is going on with this tag? And what should happen to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[customization](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customization) is our trash bin. There are many, many [useless tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), and each week someone invents a new one.

We cannot really delete tags, so I merge other nonsense tags into this to avoid *untagged* posts. Maybe I should rename the tag to `ban-me`, so people stop using it.

Our tags are a [mess](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/984/tag-soup-clean-up). `customization` is just the most visible symptom. It doesn’t mean anything.

Comment: Yes, let's rename this to something more obviously a junk tag, if possible. I'd go with `do-not-use-this-ever` but that is just me. :)

Comment: "... each week someone invents a new one..."-- the rep needed to create a tag is (absurdly) low. Can that be changed?

Comment: @s_ha_dum We already tried, but there seems to be [too less support](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/741/adding-tags-should-have-a-min-cap-of-5k) for it...

Comment: @kaiser, I upvoted that question in your comment. I don't know if it will do any good.

Comment: @s_ha_dum So far any efforts to change the internals of the system have been ignored... SO itself has 1k+ for adding tags _facepalm_