# Adopt a tag! Help to keep our site clean

Tags: discussion, tags

[Our tags are a mess](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/984/tag-soup-clean-up): many questions are tagged wrongly, and many tags are too similar or meaningless.

Some time ago, I cleaned up the tags [wordpress.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress.com) and [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress.org). Since then I check those tags regularly for new questions and remove the tags if they weren’t used properly.

Now I ask you to do the same: pick two or more related tags (for example [jquery](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jquery) and [jquery-ui](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jquery-ui)) and help us to improve our site over time.

There isn’t much to do after the initial clean up. Keep an eye on the tag wiki, and make sure new questions are tagged properly. When you see two tags which should merged, open a new topic here or [suggest the synonym](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms).

Name the tags in your answer, so we know which are taken already.

Answer (score 6):

I'll take `<query-posts>` and `<pagination>` (and any others related to custom query loops/pagination).

Comment: I think you’ll need help with that. There are also [tag:query], [tag:wp-query] and related tags with _many_ questions.

Comment: That's why I'm going to focus on *pagination* questions first. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I take [wordpress.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress.com) and [wordpress.org](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wordpress.org)

The tag wikis are still not good enough.

Answer (score 2):

I'll handle [custom-post-types](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custom-post-types).

Comment: Start with one of them. Both are very active tags, could be too much.

Comment: Fair enuff. Will put the focus on CPTs.

Answer (score 1):

I'll adopt [ajax](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ajax) as primary one. I'll take care of the *related* [jquery](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jquery) and [javascript](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) as well when they appear in those questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take `<url-rewriting>` `<rewrite-rules>` and similar.

Comment: Cool. There are many tags in this area which need to be consolidated. If you can come up with a good plan, open a new thread here please. These tags are a mess right now. We should try to focus on the concept, not on function names.

Comment: I started with the first results page just to *taste* the territory. And, yes, it's a mess. I will crete a new tread, to let community which is the better way to do this. @toscho

Answer (score 0):

I take [woocommerce](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce) as it's an easy one.

Comment: Please, no. You are [not exactly unbiased](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2412/make-woocommerce-questions-off-topic).

Comment: +1. Close All The Woo Things