# Rename the advanced-custom-fields tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've been browsing topics on Advanced Custom Fields, and I notice the tag does not follow the trend of prefixing `plugin-`, as other plugins tags have done. Should we rename [advanced-custom-fields](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advanced-custom-fields) to [plugin-advanced-custom-fields](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-advanced-custom-fields)?

Answer (score 7):

It irks me now and then, but it there is 25 characters limit for tag name. And [plugin-acf](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-acf) seems a little too abbreviated.

Any alternate suggestions?

Comment: I had been thinking `plugin-acf`, as ACF seems a well-known acronym for the plugin. Though as you say it's maybe too short to be useful. Haven't any other idea at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Tags don't really have ever had a convention. It's mostly what the one who has the capability to add one, thinks in exactly the second he adds it.

Then there's the thing that autocomplete doesn't care about beginning of words, etc. It just completes. And the only really reason for renaming would be autocomplete. So I really don't care about the name of a single tag.

If you really want to help with tags, then **[please come and adopt a tag](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2659/adopt-a-tag-help-to-keep-our-site-clean)**. :)

Comment: Ehh, I just like consistency :)