# Why are old questions on the front page?

Tags: discussion

After answering a few questions recently I noticed that they were months, if not years, old.. which tends to mean that the likelihood of an answer ever being accepted is slim.

Not that it is the end of the world, but they were all the front page of the WPSE site... so I was curious how old questions were ending up there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we have low activity, the [Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) brings old, unanswered questions to the front page. A question is *unanswered* if there is no accepted or upvoted answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. Yes, I noticed the "Community" bot's name after the fact. A different question: is there a way to accept answers for users who've disappeared? Otherwise, some questions will never get answers.

Comment: No, only the asker can accept an answer. But upvoting existing answers will move those questions out of the [list of unanswered questions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/unanswered).

Comment: My only concern with this is when I post a comment like "Can you please update your question with..." and notice that it was asked years back lol

Answer (score 2):

With [the Adopt-A-Tag initiative](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2659/adopt-a-tag-help-to-keep-our-site-clean), you may also see old questions moved to the front of the queue again, since tag edits and other cleanup will have similar effect, IIRC.

Comment: Yeah, when I cleaned up the `wordpress.org` tag, I owned the _complete_ front page for an hour. Oops! :)